# foreach loop through an array that has directory paths and filenames(perl)

Tags: perl

```
1440665    8 drwxrwx---   2 smithjoe   smithjoe      1024 May 29 09:01 .
1960596    8 -rwxrwx--x   1 smithjoe   smithjoe      3190 May 29 09:00 ./file1.prl
3197096    8 -rw-rw----   1 smithjoe   smithjoe      1594 May 24 16:11 .dir/documents/file2.prl~
1790401    8 -rw-------   1 smithjoe   smithjoe      3205 May 29 09:01 .dir/files/file3.prl
6754401    8 -rw-------   1 smithjoe   smithjoe      3205 May 29 09:01 .smithjoe/file3.prl
2737401    8 -rw-------   1 smithjoe   smithjoe      3205 May 29 09:01 .smithjoe/folder2
```

I have an array(@file_path) with the data presented above. i want to be able to extract the file/dir name out of the array(it's the last element on the line). I have to use foreach loop. once i do that. I skip the directories and save them in a new array. i append that array with the push command.

help me out. please.

Comment: How did you come up with such array? There are better ways to read directory.

Comment: @mpapec: Given the statement "I have to use foreach loop", I'm guessing this is homework and parsing the output of `ls -l` is also one of the parameters of the assignment.

Comment: @DaveSherohman it seems that teachers have profound ways to assign homeworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd re-iterate @mpapec's comment, that you probably want to first approach this by fixing the data you get in, rather than trying to manipulate it. Also, I need to prefix this by saying that this WILL choke on whitespace inside filenames and paths -- and I'm not sure there's a good, reliable way to avoid that which doesn't introduce other quirks, hence the recommendation to fix up the data before you try to process it.

But, if you're stuck with the data you have, and you're confident you won't have whitespace in filenames/paths:

```
my @paths;
foreach my $line (@file_path) {
    my @parts = split /\s+/, $line;
    push @paths, $parts[-1];
}
```

...should get you on your way.

Comment: @sohailkhan I'm confused as to what you want; in my example, at least when I tested it, @paths contained the last part (i.e. the path and filename bit) from each line of `ls` output. As in, http://pastebin.ca/2384570

Comment: where does 2384570 come from? Do you want the *first* part of each line of the output rather than the last? Because a bunch of people have been answering this on the assumption you wanted the last.

Anyway if you do, just replace `[-1]` with `[0]` to take the first part instead of the last.

Comment: Ahah. That's probably safest of all -- you can replace `/\s+/` with `/\//` in the call to `split`, and my original code example will give you everything after the very last `/` on each line -- i.e. the filename.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html should help you split the last part of each line into a list, and then http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html has the information you need to handle that list (possibly by sticking it into an array).

Answer (score 2):

A couple hints for you:

- Assuming that the file paths will never contain spaces, you can use the `split` command to separate the fields on each line and assign them to an array.  If they can contain spaces, `split` takes an optional third parameter for the maximum number of fields to return.
- In Perl, `$array[-1]` returns the last item in `@array`.

Those two tips should allow you to get the file path from each line.

Comment: @sohailkhan `perldoc -f split`

Comment: You could use ls without the -l option -- and, then you'd already have your data ready to iterate through with foreach :-)

Comment: If you got your data by a different method, then the way that your alternate source formatted the data would determine what you have to do.

Comment: @mpapec I always forget about using `-1` explicitly -- it's implied if you pipe into something else (which is where I always want it) -- so cheers for the reminder :-)